# how to accept a mac address from input and print next three macaddress in python

Tags: python, hex, mac-address

I am new to Python and coding. My requirement is simple.

I will prompt the user for a macaddress. When it is entered, I will print the next 3 mac addresses. For example if the mac address entered is 00:00:00:00:00:00, I should be able to print next 3 mac addresses in the format
00:00:00:00:00:01
00:00:00:00:00:02
00:00:00:00:00:03

Pls help

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? It seems like you're trying to get some code, I know you're new to coding and python but you won't progress if you ask others to code for you. Try something yourself and if you're stuck then ask, don't just ask of the bat (hence the downvote)

Comment: How do you know that I've n't tried ? I've tried various methods such as assigning the input to a hexa decimal list,integer list and then trying to add the last item in the list by 1 but it didn't work.

Comment: You haven't posted any code to show that you have! How can we help you if you don't show us the code!

Answer (score 0):

You can validate macaddress like this:

```
def isMAC48Address(inputString):
if inputString.count(":")!=5:
    return False
for i in inputString.split(":"):
    for j in i:
        if j>"F" or (j<"A" and not j.isdigit()) or len(i)!=2:
            return False
return True
```

Answer (score 0):

First use a regular expression to validate your MAC address. If it is in the correct format then simply remove the `:` characters to give you a single HEX value which can be converted into an integer. Use this integer to count the next 3 values. For each integer, convert the value back into a HEX string (with suitable zero padding at the front). Then print the output, putting the missing `:` characters back in:4

```
import re

mac_address = input('Please enter a MAC address: ')
valid = re.match('(?=[a-f0-9]{2}:){5}[a-f0-9]{2}', mac_address, re.I)

if valid:
    mac_as_int = int(mac_address.replace(':', ''), 16)

    for address in range(mac_as_int + 1, mac_as_int + 4):
        output = '{:012X}'.format(address)
        print('{}:{}:{}:{}:{}:{}'.format(output[0:2], output[2:4], output[4:6], output[6:8], output[8:10], output[10:12]))
else:
    print('Invalid MAC address')
```

This will correctly handle the case where a value carries over into the next block:

```
Please enter a MAC address: 00:00:00:00:00:00
00:00:00:00:00:01
00:00:00:00:00:02
00:00:00:00:00:03

Please enter a MAC address: 11:22:33:44:55:FE
11:22:33:44:55:FF
11:22:33:44:56:00
11:22:33:44:56:01
```